# MySQL Max Count without Order By

Tags: mysql, count, max

I have the following MySQL line:

`SELECT age, count(*) AS total FROM pacient WHERE age BETWEEN 20 AND 40 GROUP BY age ORDER BY age` and I need to add an additional column to it that shows ONLY the max value of the count(*) for every row. For example:

13 2 7
18 2 7
23 5 7
24 7 7
26 6 7
32 3 7
38 1 7
41 1 7
46 4 7

This would be 3 columns and the 3rd column shows 7 since 7 was the highest number in the second column where the count(*) is made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here the solution:

```
select age,
    count(*),
    (select max(c) from 
        (select count(*) as c from pacient where age between 20 and 40 group by age) as x) as t 
from pacient 
where age between 20 and 40 
group by age 
order by age;
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to wrap your query with another query? something like

```
SELECT A.age, A.total, MAX(A.total) as max_value FROM (
    SELECT age, count(*) AS total 
    FROM pacient
    WHERE age BETWEEN 20 AND 40 
    GROUP BY age ORDER BY age) as A
GROUP BY A.age, A.total
```

Comment: The 2nd and 3rd column give the same results. I need for the 3rd column to give only the highest value from the 2nd column. See?

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
      p.Age,
      count(*)  CountPerAge,
      max(ar.AllRecs) AllRecs
   from
      pacient p,
      ( select count(*) AllRecs 
           from pacient p2
           where p2.age between 20 and 40 ) ar
   where 
      p.age between 20 and 40
   group by
      p.age
```

By doing a join to the second "subselect" with no join condition, it will give a Cartesian result... Since it is a count with no group by, it will always return a single record and thus be joined to all age rows otherwise.  The MAX() of the value is no problem since it is the only record will just be returned as-is.

Comment: It throws the same error I got before posting: "Every derived table must have its own alias". I still gave a +1 for the explanation of the subselect and the no group by giving the cartesian result. I will keep that in mind.

Comment: Now it gave me the sum of all of them. Instead of showing the max value which is 15, it gave me 64 which is the sum. Which BTW is another great idea if somebody was to sum all the values.

Comment: @Cyrex,  dooohhh!!! with all the other complex queries I've helped out others on... Completely misread the MAX() you wanted   :)

Answer (score 0):

It is always good to use SQL VIEWS instead of using sub queries. Because VIEW will be having already compiled result.

```
CREATE VIEW subqueryView 
    SELECT age, count(*) AS total 
    FROM pacient
    WHERE age BETWEEN 20 AND 40 
    GROUP BY age ORDER BY age

SELECT A.age, A.total, MAX(A.total) as max_value FROM (SELECT FROM subqueryView) as A
GROUP BY A.age, A.total
```